# eval-when-compile in terms of minor-mode development

Tags: byte-compilation, eval

I'd like to know when a developer should use `eval-when-compile` despite the fact that at first glance everything works without `eval-when-compile`.

1. When does not using `eval-when-compile` lead to unexpected behavior?
2. In the presence of `defmacro`, what is the reason to use eval-when-compile?

Comment: The Elisp manual, node [Evaluation During Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Compile.html), explains the motivation / use cases quite clearly, IMO. You will help **yourself** by learning (better) how to **Ask Emacs**.

Comment: It might be good enough for you but not for me.  When defining a minor-mode with a `defmacro` such as in `(eval-when-compile (defmacro rainbow-delimiters--define-depth-faces ()` that occurs in `rainbow-delimiters`.  Why is it necessary?  When does compilation happen?  I put things in my init file and run emacs, thus I do not encounter compilation much.  Is this about byte compilation?

Comment: Yes, that is why the documentation for `eval-when-compile` is part of [chapter 17 Byte Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Byte-Compilation.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual. Notice that this documentation includes three examples of when you might need to use it. Most of the time you do not need it.

Comment: I did not know that some files require byte-compilation.  What is special about byte compilation apart from the faster runtimes?  Do emacs packages customarily get byte compiled?

Comment: Where did you see that some files require byte-compilation?

Comment: Let's keep it civil, folks.

Comment: @Dan, if that's addressed to me, it's an honest question: I haven't seen anybody say here and I don't know of any doc that says that some files require byte-compliation as the OP states: " I did not know that some files require byte-compilation". So I am curious how he came to that conclusion.

Comment: @NickD: no, it's not directed at you.  There were some other comments I deleted because they were, shall we say, less than constructive.

Comment: Because I have seen `eval-when-compile` in some packages, I thought compilation would make a difference in how the package runs, and thus on the possibility that byte compilation might be required.

Answer (score 0):

`eval-when-compile` is an esoteric feature that is rarely necessary. Like any other tool, sometimes it is useful and sometimes it is not. It has nothing whatsoever to do with minor modes; they are orthogonal. A minor mode might use `eval-when-compile`, or it might not. The choice is usually up to the author of the mode, when they are deciding how to structure the code that they are writing. It is just as often used for code that implements things other than minor modes. The same goes for all other Lisp features as well.

[Chapter 17.5 Evaluation During Compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval-During-Compile.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual gives all the information there is to know about it, including examples of when it is useful.

This question was downvoted is because it will never help anyone else, and because of its combinatorial nature. Emacs has a large number of features; let us say that there are N of them. That means that there are N² number of questions that people could ask about combining features. None of them are likely to be well received.

A better question to ask might have been “Why does the rainbow-delimiters minor mode use `eval-when-compile` on line NNN?” This at least has a concrete answer, though it is possible that nobody would want to do the kind of detailed archaeology necessary to answer it properly. You might be better off emailing the author, though there are downsides to that as well.

Comment: Then I shall ask the concrete question that has a concrete answer.

Comment: Have read the definition of the macro, but I disagree that it really provides hints on when to use it, its advantages etc.  It is rather a summary and short description that stays rather abstract.

Comment: If you can’t see the three examples in the documentation then you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Anybody can use the form but there is no compelling analysis on why one needs Byte Compilation.

Comment: Why do you expect a “compelling analysis”, and from whom do you expect it?

Comment: Because from reading it is no evident focus on the necessity to byte compile except for making the code run faster.  Mostly it is about how to use it.  From somebody who can show experience on the needs for byte compilation in order to make something work as expected.

Comment: Right, the whole purpose of compilation is speed. This applies to everything, not just Emacs. Why is C compiled? For speed. Why is Java compiled? Speed. Etc.

Comment: From your discussion I could conclude that any elisp code will execute properly without byte compilation.  But, for instance, things that perform dynamic analysis of a buffer while typing would benefit from having some functions  or macros byte compiled.